# Using "this" object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare a JavaScript object like so:

```
var Calculator = function() {
    this.textbox = new Textbox({
        ...
    });
    this.btn1 = new Button ({
        ...
        onClick: function() {
            this.textbox.value += "1";
    });
    ...
};
```

I did some debugging and found that the `this` object inside `this.btn1` no longer refers to the `Calculator` object. How can I reference `textbox` to the `Calculator`'s `textbox`?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old trick of `var self = this`

```
var Calculator = function() {
    var self = this;  // self is a reference to calculator, always.

    this.textbox = new Textbox({
        ...
    });
    this.btn1 = new Button ({
        ...
        onClick: function() {
            self.textbox.value += "1";
    });
    ...
};
```

Comment: I like `that` more.

Comment: As I know, the problem with using `this` was solved in ES6 via arrow functions (`() => {...}`)

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response! My code works now! I will accept your answer when the timer cools off.